# How to write if all values in the array are null using an array filter

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to display an error message within a view if a customer has not selected a product, which is a boolean in the database. This currently display the message but also stays once a selected column is true.

```
<?php
$company1 = DB::table('customers')->select('post', 'telans','conum')->where('business', $user )->get();
print_r($company1);
?>

@if (array_filter($company1))

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
Please <strong><a href="/user_register">click here</a></strong> to select your products</strong>
</div>
@endif
```

The array print is as follows if it helps:

**Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [post] => [telans] => [conum] => ) )**

Comment: You can use ```array_filter()```, refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I have a better understanding now. So the function would be checking for NULL

Comment: It would filter the array values and return new array, So you can do something like ```count(array_filter($myarr))```

Comment: I am going to kick myself when I see it, but would you be able to supply an example?

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

I needed to remove the object stdClass and a few tweaks.

```
<?php
function checkIsset($val) {
    return count(array_filter($val));
}

$company1 = DB::table('customers')->select('post', 'telans','conum')->where('business', $user )->get();

$array = json_decode(json_encode($company1), true);

$filteredArr = array_filter($array, 'checkIsset');

print_r( $array);
//dd($filteredArr);
?>
@if (count(array_filter($filteredArr)) == 0)
@if ( !is_null($company)) 


<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
Please <strong><a href="/user_register">click here</a></strong> to select your products</strong>
</div>
@endif 
@endif
```